# The tag even-and-odd-extensions

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management, tag-wikis

So there's this tag [even-and-odd-extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/even-and-odd-extensions).

There are 16 questions with this tag which consist of:

1. Even and odd functions
2. Even and odd integers
3. Even and odd digits of a number
4. Extending a function to an even or odd function over $\mathbb{R}$
5. Something to do with the wave function

From a brief Google search, it appears that this has something to do with Fourier analysis and differential equations, definitely not my expertise.

My request:

1. Could we, first of all, decide whether we even need this tag?
2. And if we decide we need it, could someone with more expertise than I have please edit the tag wiki and change the tags on these 16 questions appropriately?

[Tag management 2018 thread link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27749/81560)

Comment: It seems that the tag was created [about a year ago](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2017/1/7). Perhaps it would be reasonable to notify also the tag creator that there is a discusison about this tag.

Comment: @MartinSleziak By the way, out of curiosity, how do you find the creator of a tag? The [tag info page](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/even-and-odd-extensions/info) tells me nothing about the creator.

Comment: I [searched in the tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=even-and-odd-extensions&room=3740). This [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/542457/first-10-uses-of-a-tag?tagName=even-and-odd-extensions) seems to confirm that this was most likely the first post in the tag. (Admittedly, neither of those is 100% reliable.) See also: [Can you tell who created a tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25038).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I've [pinged](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42354417#42354417) the creator. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I consider the tag [even-and-odd-extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/even-and-odd-extensions) too specific to be really useful. (Having too specific tags applicable only to very narrow class of questions can cause problem since there are only five spots available for tags.)

My suggestion is to create a new tag [even-and-odd-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/even-and-odd-functions). This tag is at least slightly more general. It might be potentially useful, since questions about even and odd questions are common in various introductory courses. Moreover, if you look at the questions which currently have (even-and-odd-extensions) tag, they are actually about even/odd functions.

<sup>It is possible that some users might consider even the new proposed tag (even-and-odd-functions) as too narrow. We will see the opinion of the community in the voting and comments on this answer. (And maybe somebody will post an alternative answer suggesting to eliminate the tags related to odd and even functions entirely.)</sup>

I will also point out that moderators are able to change name of a tag to a different name without [bumping](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bumping/info) all questions. This can be done by creating the tag with the new name and then merging the two tags. If somebody is interested in details on this, see here: [Can you change the name of a tag?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25699)

Comment: I've upvoted, but I would just delete the tag and not replace it with anything.  This isn't an active tag, and (functions) or (number theory) would be a better tag than something this specific.  Most of the time when these topics come up, they're contained within some larger context.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Maybe you could expand you comment and post it as an answer - that way other users will have opportunity to vote on the answer which suggests removal. (I would not be surprised to learn that there are many users who share your opinion.)

Comment: I am the person who created the tag. If you're going to do something, I suggest what @MartinSleziak suggested. In the field of PDEs, having a tag like this might be useful.